# Why is lord Vishnu taking many avatars while Parashurama is presnt?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

I have heard that lord parashurama is living as chiranjeevi in the hills of mahendra then what is a need of another avatars?

why lord parashurama can't destroy adharma throughout the yugas?

Comment: @AnuragSingh but how you know that this is copied from the western? It maybe from OP himself

Comment: @rakeshjoshi whoever did it, usually I saw this kind of transliterations in western translators. But the point is writing j as g makes pronounciations erraneous. Thanks you understood

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be understood that Lord Parashurama was an avesha avatara. That means he was designated to be an avatara for a specific purpose for specific period of time.

He technically ceased to be an avatara when he met Sri rama who was already an avatara.

That means his goals were accomplished and therein he continued to live as a rishi and guru.

Dharma and adharma coexist always. Adharma can be controlled to an extent by special avataras or prophets but it cannot be abolished forever. This is the law of nature.

Comment: Sources. Please.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan do you need source for both of them being avatara ?

Comment: Not necessary. This doesn't seem to be correct understanding though: "Dharma and adharma coexist always. Adharma can be controlled to an extent by special avataras or prophets but it cannot be.abolished forever. This is the law of nature."

Comment: The story of Parshurama Avatara is enumerated in many scriptures - Valmiki Ramayana - Bala Kaanda - describes the encounter of Rama Rama and says Parshurama gives up his powers to Sri Rama and moves to become an asetic - His avatara is complete. Parshurama appears also in Mahabharata as the preceptor of both Devavrata (Bhisma) and Karna - and of course his avatara is described in full in Srimad bhagavatam. Rakesh Joshi's reply does not need any sources and any user asking for the same must be unaware of these sources.

Comment: @SureshRamaswamy That doesn't work like that on the site. For the sake of quality, sources should be added. If it is referred that many times, why is it difficult to add them in the answers? Why can't the user himself add it in the answer? Is it not being very stubborn?